# Grails 2.3.5 app won't start in AppFog with MySQL binding

Tags: grails

I am trying to deploy a Grails 2.3.5 application with a MySQL binding on AppFog. I did this successfully with a Grails 2.2.4 application using the following settings in DataSource.groovy:

```
production { 
    def envVar = System.env.VCAP_SERVICES 
    def credentials = envVar?grails.converters.JSON.parse(envVar)["mysql-5.1"][0]["credentials"]:null 

    dataSource { 
        pooled = true 
        dbCreate = "update" 
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        url = credentials?"jdbc:mysql://${credentials.hostname}:${credentials.port}/${credentials.name}?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8":"" 
        username = credentials?credentials.username:"" 
        password = credentails?credentials.password:"" 
    } 
}
```

I also uncommented the runtime mysql connector statement in BuildConfig.groovy. My 2.2.4 app starts, allows data commits, and persists data after an application restart.

In my 2.3.5 application, I can deploy on AppFog without MySQL by setting the following in BuildConfig.groovy, which downgrades the build to Tomcat 6:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5"
```

and in the plugins section:

```
build ":tomcat:2.2.4"
```

The app starts and commits data, but since files do not persist, the H2 datafiles are deleted after an application restart. If I make the same changes as above to configure MySQL, I get the following error when the application starts:

```
Feb 12, 2014 6:05:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'uqVkBpKILRjxS'@'10.0.13.117' (using password: NO)
```

The logs contain much more, but that seems to be the offending error. Did something else change in Grails 2.3.5 that I need to add to my config files? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just pointing some clues:

Have you seen "(using password: NO)" in the error message? For some reason, your password is not being fetched from VCAP_SERVICES and your code is not providing any password. What happens if you do a System.out.println(envVar) inside datasource{...}? Can you see your password on the logs?